# How to send file using http protocol without encode?

Tags: php, html, http, server, wireshark

I want to send a png file to my apache server and export it using wireshark.

I tried a html form like this:

```
<form action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <p>files: <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40"></p>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

But i can't export my file as PNG. I think it happens because I use "multipart/form-data". I've heard that this encrypts the file. I'm not sure, what do you think I should try?

Comment: If I understand well, the only problem here is extension of file?

Comment: No, the file extension doesn't matter. I just want to capture and export the file with wireshark.

Comment: first of all `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required for when you upload file. How do you even handle file upload? Do you move file inside of some folder inside of the server, do you save the name of it inside of the database? Do you have general name ruling?

Comment: You can't extract what's even not there. 
When it comes to enctype meaning, you totally missed it  `“multipart/form-data” ` "tells" that no characters are encoded (Encoding is basically that spaces are converted to “+” symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values).

Comment: I am saving the file in uploads/ folder in my apache2 server.